# Looking for Skills Taxonomy with Industry specific

Tags: data-request, usa, metadata

Like O*NET database which have skills categorized on based on occupations defined by [BLS Standard Occupations](https://www.bls.gov/soc/2018/major_groups.htm), is there any dataset similar that can provide skills categorized based on industries as well?